# Angular select option

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have select option for `states` and `cities`, I want when I select state, cities related to that state shows in second select field.

## Screenshot

`states list`

[image: one]

`cities list`

[image: two]

## Code

`HTML`

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Pilih Province</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="province_id" multiple="false" placeholder="Pihil Province">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let state of states" value="state.province_id">{{state.province}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Pilih Kota</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="kota_id" multiple="falsee" placeholder="Pilih Kota">
    <ion-select-option value="peperoni">Peperoni</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="hawaii">Hawaii</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

`toko.page.ts`

```
export class AddTokoPage implements OnInit {

  states: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private statesService: StatesService, //service for returning states and cities
  ) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allStates();
  }

  //get states list
  allStates(){
    this.statesService.getStates().subscribe((res) => {
      for (let state of res) {
        this.states.push(state);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

> Note: obviously in my code above I need cities function and that's
>   where I need your help to get those cities lists.

`states.service.ts`

```
export class StatesService {

  token: any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private env: EnvService,
    private storage: NativeStorage
  ) {
    this.storage.getItem('token').then((token) => {
      this.token = token;
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  getStates(): Observable<any> {

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(`${this.env.STATES_URL}`, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(states => states.data)
    );
  }

  getCities(id) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(`${this.env.CITIES_URL}/${id}`, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(cities => cities)
    );
  }
}
```

**Any idea hw to get my cities list based on selected state?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to 'ionChange' event when someone selects a state. For e.g.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Pilih Province</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="province_id" multiple="false" placeholder="Pihil Province" #state (ionChange)="onChange(state.value)">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let state of states" value="state.province_id">{{state.province}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

and in the listener you can call your service

```
onChange(value) {
    // call your service to fetch cities
    console.log(value);
    this.cities = /* your success response*/
}
```

**EDIT:**
Then you can populate these cities on HTML

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Cities</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="cities" multiple="false">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of cities | async" value="city.city_id">{{city.name}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: and how do I target cities select in order to return data there?

Comment: You get the cities data in an array and re-populate your select box based on the data.

Comment: and my question is how? in JavaScript for instance we provide `id` or `class` then in `success` we get that `id` or `class` to return data in there, now in angular how's that working?

Comment: If you are after how angular change detection cycle works you can read it about here https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html... BTW I've updated the HTML part as well

Comment: Hi, I've tested your approach it is working but there is a small issue, when I change my selected state it doesn't clear cities of old state instead it just add new cities to old ones. how do i remove old cities?

Comment: You can clear the 'cities'
- if array - this.cities.length = 0;
- if object - this.cities = {};

Answer (score 0):

In your component

```
export class AddTokoPage implements OnInit {

cities:any[]=[] // definecities

onStateSelect(stateid){
this.stateService.getCities(stateid).subscribe(data=>{
this.cities=data;
})
}
```

on html side add `ionChange` to your state dropdown

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Pilih Province</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="province_id" multiple="false" placeholder="Pihil Province" #state (ionChange)="onStateChange(state.value)">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let state of states" value="state.province_id">{{state.province}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

And add code for your cities dropdown

```
<ion-item *ngIf="cities?.length">
    <ion-label>Cities</ion-label>
    <ion-select  multiple="false" #cities>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of cities" value="city.yourcityfield">{{city.fieldToDisplay}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```